# Creating a SPA (single page App) on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, angularjs, react, spa

I am new to the SharePoint world & I have been assigned to make a Single-page Application using any Framework (ReactJS/Angular) on SharePoint online (Microsoft 365).

The Application needs to take the whole screen, and integrate with SharePoint lists & Library.

I Have been doing some research lately, but I could not find anything straight forward that would get me going.

Edit: From my understand SPFX is used to create Web-parts that take a portion of a page. However for my case i am trying to create an App that takes over the whole page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single part app page to develop single page application in SharePoint using SPFx. Follow below URL to try it.

[Single Page App using SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages)

Comment: This looks promising Thanks, i'll mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint Online, you can use **SharePoint Framework** for development.

You can use React JS, Angular or any other JavaScript framework you are familiar with SharePoint Framework.

Following articles will help you start with SharePoint Framework.

**References**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).
2. [SharePoint Framework client-side web parts with Angular JS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-client-side-web-parts-with-angular-1-x).
3. [SharePoint Framework - CRUD Operations Using ReactJS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-crud-operations-using-react-js/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, i have done some reading over SPFX, but what im trying to do is quite different. i want to create a an application that takes over the whole Sharepoint page. Cause from my understanding SPFX is used to create apart of a page.